# ec2-consistent-snapshot volume does not exist?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Does anybody know why this might happen?

```
me@ip-10-176-234-62:/$ ec2-describe-volumes
VOLUME  vol-994ec1fd    8   snap-2971f04d   us-west-1a  in-use  2012-05-14T18:57:01+0000
ATTACHMENT  vol-994ec1fd    i-a49a2ae2  /dev/sda1   attached    2012-08-31T18:39:18+0000

me@ip-10-176-234-62:/$ ec2-consistent-snapshot vol-994ec1fd --aws-access-key-id xxxx --aws-secret-access-key xxxxx
    ec2-consistent-snapshot: ERROR: The volume 'vol-994ec1fd' does not exist.
```

Comment: Any chance that `ec2-consistent-snapshot` is using a different credential pair without access to that volume?

Comment: Yep, the volume either is in a different region or belongs to a different account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to specify the region on the command-line, e.g.:

```
--region us-west-1a
```

Comment: This is was the issue: The default region is "us-east-1" so you need to explicitly state the region of your volume. Needed one small amendment, my region needed to be input as `us-west-1` - thanks for the help.